# typeset -A is giving error in script

Tags: bash, array, typeset

I was using associative arrays in my script, hence I used to declare them by the

`typeset -A <array_name>` command, and it worked fine in the bash prompt

But when I use it in my script, I get the following error 

`typeset: -A: invalid option
typeset: usage: typeset [-afFirtx] [-p] name[=value] ...`

An alternative solution will also be acceptable for me.

SIDENOTE: I tried typeset -a but it declares an indexed array. But I want an associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the error generated by Bash 3 for `typeset -A`. [Associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) were added in Bash 4, and [are not in](http://bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-3.2/doc/bashref.html#SEC81) Bash 3.2 and earlier.

It seems that your script is being run with a different version of Bash than you are using as your shell. If you're on the same machine in both cases, you have multiple versions installed and can probably select one with a different path. If you're on a different machine running the script, you may be able to install a newer version, but otherwise you're out of luck for direct support in Bash.

`zsh` supports associative arrays since much older versions, so if you have that available you can likely port your script without too much work. If you're unable to do that, you can fake it with regular arrays and `grep`, or using [`${!prefix@}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-expansion_002c-parameter) and a set of ordinary variables, which is available in older Bash versions. `${!prefix@}` expands to the names of all variables whose names start with `prefix`, which you can use in combination with several variables `prefix_key1`, `prefix_another` to get most of the behaviours of associative arrays.

Comment: Hi Michael, will `zsh 4.2.6 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` support associative arrays?

Comment: `zsh` has had associative arrays since version 4 (released 2001), so they should be fine.

Comment: Hi Michael, for the following statement

`for KEY in ${!array[@]}`

zsh is giving `bad substitution` error. Any idea why?

Comment: See [`man zshexpn`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) for the details of `zsh` parameter expansion. Otherwise, asking a new question about `zsh` will get more attention from others too.