# Bad substitution error in zsh shell

Tags: zsh, array

Hi in my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150015/typeset-a-is-giving-error-in-script/150023?noredirect=1#comment243933_150023) I got clarity on how to use associative arrays in zsh shell.

But whenever I trigger the following command in my script

`for KEY in ${!array[@]}` to iterate amongst the keys in my array

I get a `bad substitution` error.

even `echo ${!array[@]}` gives the same.

NB: `array` is the name of my associative array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`zsh` has different parameter substitution than Bash, which is documented in [`man zshexpn`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn). It supports a variety of [modifiers to expansion behaviour](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags), which are put in parentheses before the variable name: `${(X)name}`. The modifier to include array keys (including for associative arrays) is `k`: `${(k)array}` expands to the list of keys in the array, except that if a key is the empty string, it is omitted. Use double quotes and the `@` modifier to retain the empty key.

```
for x in "${(@k)array}" ; ...
```

will loop over the keys of the array `array`.

Comment: `${(k)array}` expands to the  _non-empty_ keys. Use `"${(k@)array}"` if there may be empty keys.

Answer (score 6):

You must use `"${(@k)array}"`, `"${(k)array}"` only expands to the non-empty keys:

```
typeset -A array
array=(k1 v1 k2 v2 k3 v3)

for k in "${(@k)array}"; do
  printf "%s -> %s\n" "$k" "$array[$k]"
done
```

Then:

```
$ zsh test.zsh 
k1 -> v1
k2 -> v2
k3 -> v3
```

You can also replace `for` loop with key, value expansion:

```
printf '%s -> %s\n' "${(@kv)array}"
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `${!...}` doesn't exist. I suppose you want: `${(k)array[@]}`, or simply `${(k)array}`. For more information, see the `zshexpn(1)` man page, which says for the `k` expansion flag: "If name refers to an associative array, substitute the keys (element names) rather than the values of the elements."

Comment: what is AFAIK? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: as far as I know

Comment: `${(k)array}` expands to the  _non-empty_ keys. Use `"${(k@)array}"` if there may be empty keys.